# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

One of [The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.

We have designers on staff to come up with site designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as exceptional, we are happy to use it.

- One suggestion per answer please, for voting purposes.

[Logo guidance, from Jin](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshot) (resident UI designer for at least some of the Stack Exchange sites):

> Please note: I prefer gray-scaled logo submissions, that way we can judge the IDEA of the logo more objectively. We can always add colors to the logo later. Also, the logo itself(sans the site title text) should be able to fit in a square dimension nicely. This way we can use it for favicons, mobile touch icons etc.

Comment: Thank you for starting this post. Even though this site may be months away from being launched officially, it's always good to get design discussion going early.

Comment: Film with audio logo inside for the icon?

Answer (score 8):

- What about the up/down buttons as retro-toggle switches, e.g.

  http://www.istockphoto.com/file_closeup/isolated-objects/263586-old-chrome-toggle-switch.php?id=263586
- The upvote numbers could be in "db"
- I like a vu meter for the logo, or maybe a high-end mic
- Tags could look like marker-on-tape like you'd label a console channel

I'm not super artistic, so sorry I don't have any images…

Comment: Awesome ideas!!

Comment: I like the idea of the masking tape tags.  Not a fan of the toggle switch idea though.  It doesn't seem as intuitive as arrows, but that's just me.

Comment: Like the VoltMeter and marker-on-tape ideas. Not so keen on the microphone idea or the things to do with up/down vote, I don't think they'll just change the look/feel I think they'll be a bit confusing!

Answer (score 2):

Why change it? I love it exactly as it is :-)

Comment: +1 Love your response, but we will want want to give the site a design for multiple reasons: Identity, Recognition, Disjoint from other betas, ... I'm pretty sure you would love the design we would go for. If not, then there's always room for improvement! :-)

Comment: How about a retro-looking "Recording Now" red light sign as a logo?

Comment: Please note that our site is there for more than just recording.

Answer (score 2):

An old-school record button, like here:

[image]

Because almost all audio/video production starts from recording.

Or a play/pause button(there are many variations of this one):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the tag icons could look like mini strips of [analogue film](http://www.google.co.uk/search?um=1&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=899&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=analog%20film&btnG=Search#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=analogue%20film&pbx=1&oq=analogue%20film&aq=f&aqi=g2g-S5g-mS2&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11125l13479l2l13933l15l11l0l0l0l0l632l1203l2-1.1.0.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=44dd50c4f8219088&biw=1280&bih=899)?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to think of things that fit both audio and video, not as a logo per say, just as theme-ing for the site :)

- XLR connectors
- Cables
- Consoles?
- Cables
- Mics
- Cables

[image: XLR Cables]
[image: CABLES!!]
[image: Ummm]
Okay, this one's just funny